# How to convert "0" and "1" to false and true

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, odbc, boolean-logic

I have a method which is connecting to a database via Odbc. The stored procedure which I'm 
calling has a return value which from the database side is a 'Char'. Right now I'm grabbing
that return value as a string and using it in a simple if statement. I really don't like the idea
of comparing a string like this when only two values can come back from the database, 0 and 1.

```
OdbcCommand fetchCommand = new OdbcCommand(storedProc, conn);

fetchCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
fetchCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@column ", myCustomParameter);
fetchCommand.Parameters.Add("@myReturnValue", OdbcType.Char, 1)
            .Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
fetchCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

string returnValue = fetchCommand.Parameters["@myReturnValue"].Value.ToString();
if (returnValue == "1")
{
    return true;
}
```

What would be the proper way to handle this situation. I've tried 'Convert.ToBoolean()' which seemed
like the obvious answer but I ran into the 'String was not recognized as a valid Boolean. ' exception being thrown. Am I missing something
here, or is there another way to make '1' and '0' act like true and false?

Thanks!

Answer (score 185, accepted):

How about:

```
return (returnValue == "1");
```

or as suggested below:

```
return (returnValue != "0");
```

The correct one will depend on what you are looking for as a success result.

Comment: I would recommend using `return (returnValue!="0")`. It would be more natural that `0` is `false` and every number that is not zero is `true`. Of course here we have the case where Chris uses strings instead of numbers, so this comment is only partly valid ;)

Comment: It's always a debate. 0 also mean ERROR_SUCCESS which mean that everything went well. But I agree with Gacek that it is more natural.

Comment: Don't forget to check for nulls:   !string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnValue) && (returnValue == "1")

Comment: why not Convert.ToBoolean(1)? It does the same and you are using the framework for the check. I like the answer above as well, but which one is better to be used?

Comment: I'm currently struggling with dbnull values (that we guess. should be false too)... if you're unlucky enough to have a table where nulls are all of a sudden allowed... :|

Comment: here is how I implemented your help :) 
`var activeParam = Status == 0 ? "" : $"&active={Status == 1}";`

Answer (score 136):

In a single line of code:

```
bool bVal = Convert.ToBoolean(Convert.ToInt16(returnValue))
```

Comment: I like your version Chris because as the question stated, lets use boolean instead of comparing strings.

Comment: I also prefer your version because it conveys the intent more clearly.

Comment: It's proper only for "1" or "0". For any other string return value is not deterministic, for example "101" is true and so on...

Comment: @szubajak I don't understand your comment. Sure it is deterministic as only 0 is false as boolean.

Answer (score 14):

If you want the conversion to always succeed, probably the best way to convert the string would be to consider `"1"` as `true` and anything else as `false` (as Kevin does).  If you wanted the conversion to fail if anything other than `"1"` or `"0"` is returned, then the following would suffice (you could put it in a helper method):

```
if (returnValue == "1")
{
    return true;
}
else if (returnValue == "0")
{
    return false;
}
else
{
    throw new FormatException("The string is not a recognized as a valid boolean value.");
}
```

Comment: Nice idea to catch the unrecognized value. Not sure I want to go that way, but still a good idea.

Comment: Very easy and simple trick.

Answer (score 9):

You can use that form:

```
return returnValue.Equals("1") ? true : false;
```

Or more simply (thanks to Jurijs Kastanovs):

```
return returnValue.Equals("1");
```

Comment: Just lose the "? true : false" bit. It's totally unnecessary. Leave it at { return returnValue.Equals("1") }

Comment: I would check for false. Every number that's not 0 usually is true.

Answer (score 5):

Set return type to numeric - you don't need a char (so don't use it); a numeric value (0/1) can be converted with Convert.ToBoolean(num)

Otherwise: use Kevin's answer

Comment: I wish that we could change the return type. But we're stuck with what it is.

Comment: `Convert.ToBoolean` accepts only True/true/False/false strings

Answer (score 2):

Or if the Boolean value is not been returned, you can do something like this:

```
bool boolValue = (returnValue == "1");
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution (vb.net):

```
Private Function ConvertToBoolean(p1 As Object) As Boolean
    If p1 Is Nothing Then Return False
    If IsDBNull(p1) Then Return False
    If p1.ToString = "1" Then Return True
    If p1.ToString.ToLower = "true" Then Return True
    Return False
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(returnValue != "1" ? false : true);
```

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to convert.Just use;

```
 bool _status = status == "1" ? true : false;
```

Perhaps you will return the values as you want.